# How to find countries name with their corresponding id's in cakephp join

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

in my website anyone can select multiple cities and their id goes to database with comma separated,but when go to join in cakephp to find countries name then how i find all countries name.This is the output i received when use find('all') in table

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [job_posting_lists] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [firm_id] => 1
                [job_title] => Software Engineer
                [number_opening] => 10
                [job_details] => American Express is embarking
                [keyword] => java,Hadoop
                [min_work_exp] => 1
                [max_work_exp] => 3
                [currency] => S$
                [ctc_from] => 10000
                [ctc_to] => 15000
                [other_ctc_details] => Incentives
                [job_loc_country] => 101,123,45,56
                [job_loc_state] => 
                [job_loc_city] => 
                [select_industry] => 4
                [skill] => 1
                [key_skill_name] => 13
                [designation] => 18
                [job_type] => Full time
                [ug_qualification] => 1,11
                [ug_stream] => Computer
                [pg_qualification] => 2
                [docterate] => Ph.D
                [reference_code] => 0
                [reference_name] => 
                [added_on] => 2016-04-18 12:15:58
                [slug] => software-engineer
                [status] => 0
                [verify] => 0
            )

    )
```

this is my cakephp query to find country name

```
$requests = $this->job_posting_lists->find('all', array('joins' => array(
array(
    'table' => 'countries',
    'alias' => 'cu',
    'type' => 'inner',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions'=> array('cu.id = job_posting_lists.job_loc_country','FIND_IN_SET(cu.id,job_posting_lists.job_loc_country)')
 ),
```

and i received empty array what i do.please help.

Comment: Always include what version of cakephp you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be not to store the list of countries within a single field, but to normalise your data structure and store them in a separate record.

The quick solution is to use the find_in_set() function in the join expression, just slightly differently than you did:

```
FIND_IN_SET(cu.id,job_posting_lists.job_loc_country)>0
```

The cu.id = job_posting_lists.job_loc_country criterion must be removed.